# Php - multiples consultas "select" usando sentencia preparada

Tags: php, mysqli

El siguiente codigo tiene la funcion de recibir multiples id de paginas, ejecutar un procedimiento para obtener sus datos y retornar un arreglo con toda esta informacion.

La funcion trabaja bien pero solo cuando es 1 iteracion, hay algo que este pasando por alto? Que puede provocar el error?

```
function getArrayToPost($pages) {
  $array_response = array();
  if($conn = createConnection()) {

      $stmt = $conn->prepare('call wp_getFbPage(?);');
      $stmt->bind_param('i', $page_id);

      foreach ($pages as $fb_pagina){
          $page_id = (int)$fb_pagina['id'];
          $stmt->execute();
          $result = $stmt->get_result();
          $page_info = $result->fetch_assoc();
          $array_response[] = $page_info;
          // break; <= si es agregado, no lanza error, 1 iteracion
      }
      $conn->close();
      $stmt->close();
  }
  return $array_response;
}
```

Error: pid 4116 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in
    /etc/apache2

Comment: Estás utilizando $page_id después del if y antes del for, pero en ese momento no existe esa variable. Revisa eso.

Comment: El error `Error: pid 4116 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump` es causado muchas veces por problemas de memoria. Si dices que cuando se hace una sola llamada funciona, es posible que esa sea la causa... Puede que tu procedure `wp_getFbPage` no esté optimizada, que el código se llame de forma indiscriminada, etc. Es fácil tener ese error en un escenario que combine por ejemplo: una consulta que sea lenta en la base de datos (o muy voluminosa) y que se llame muchas veces en corto tiempo, dentro de un bucle por ejemplo. Es muy probable que necesites **optimizar**.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, el procedimiento almacenado solo tiene la tarea de obtener un unico valor de la base de datos y no posee mas que validaciones simples, intentare optimizar de alguna manera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de varias pruebas por fin logre dar con la solucion, anteriormente estaba usando mysqli por ser bastante simple y practico de utilizar, pero para esta operacion necesite usar PDO y al final mi codigo termino asi:

```
function getFBArrayToPost($pages) {
  $conn = createPdoConnection();
  $array_response = array();

  $stmt = $conn->prepare('call wp_getFbPage(:id);');      
  foreach($pages as $fb_pagina) {
    $page_id = (int)$fb_pagina['id'];
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $page_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $page_info = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $array_response[] = $page_info;
    $stmt->closeCursor();
  }
  $conn = null;
  return $array_response;
}
```

Comment: recuerda que si tu respuesta resolvió el problema, la marques como aceptada para que ayudes a otros usuarios